# tooltip box not showing using css

Tags: css, tooltip

I am trying to show a tool tip box on hover an image. I won't be able to use jquery or any other plugin. I have to use pure css. I have seen a demo working here.

http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/tooltip_demo.html

My code:

```
<a class="tooltip" title="This is some information for our tooltip." href="#"><img id="graph_one" alt="" src="https://www.onlandscape.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Doug-Chinnery-ICM-Images-4-45x45.jpg" class="graph one">  </a>
```

Jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/txeF2/

For some reason I can't get the tooltip box.

**UPDATED** : http://jsfiddle.net/Md5E6/4/

Comment: Perhaps you should reproduce the HTML structure in the linked example first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution: [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Md5E6/)

Change `.tooltip` from `inline` to `inline-block`:

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then remove the absolute positioning from the child `img` element. This was causing the main problem; as the element was removed from the flow of the document, thus causing the parent element to have no dimensions and collapse upon itself.

Comment: Thanks Josh. But unfortunately I have to use position:absolute inside the class graph.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle now I am getting the box but the box position is too far from the image.http://jsfiddle.net/Md5E6/3/

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Well; as I said, the problem is that the parent doesn't have dimensions when the child element is absolutely positioned. If the child element needs to be absolutely positioned, then the parent element's dimensions need to be explicitly set; take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/fMXL8/ The child element is absolutely positioned, but it works because the parent's dimensions are set.

Comment: Brilliant and thank you so much for explaining the reason.I was missing the parent's dimensions.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

use like this to show tooltip

```
<a title="Create Simple Tooltip Using CSS3" class="tooltip">Some Sample CSS3 Tooltip</a>

 .tooltip
 {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
 }

 .tooltip:hover:after
 {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(title);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 220px;
 }
```

If you want to view complete code with demo here is a full tutorial [Create CSS3 Tooltip](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php)

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was my parent div had an attribute "pointer-events: none". Removing this fixed my tooltip not showing issue for the child div.